# how to identify the number of unique elements in two sparate vector?

Tags: julia

I have two very long distict vectors (that are not started at 1) and wanted to know how many element I have in totall:

For example, the first few elements are:

```
A = [220,202,122,212,141,144,174,154,127,888,758,768,455,665]

B = [555,555,661,661,252,252,789,789,789,789,789,365,369,789]
```

My question:

How to find this out? the number of unique element in A union B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`union`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.union) and [`length`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.length-Tuple%7BAbstractArray%7D) are both built-in to Julia. And `union` is a set union which removes duplicates, even when applied to vectors. Consider

```
println(length(union(A, B)))
```

or, if you're feeling particularly snazzy

```
println(length(A ∪ B))
```